# Iterative sum using recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, sicp

Given the following recursive definition of sum:

> ```
> (define (sum term a next b)
>   (if (> a b)
>       0
>       (+ (term a)
>          (sum term (next a) next b))))
> ```

And the task:

> **Exercise 1.30**
>
> The sum procedure
>   above generates a linear recursion.
>   The procedure can be rewritten so that
>   the sum is performed iteratively. Show
>   how to do this by filling in the
>   missing expressions in the following
>   definition:
>
> ```
> (define (sum term a next b)
>   (define (iter a result)
>     (if <??>
>         <??>
>         (iter <??> <??>)))
>   (iter <??> <??>))
> ```

I wrote the following code.  What do you think?

```
(define (i-sum term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b)
        result
        (iter (next a) (+ result (term a)))))
  (iter a 0))

(define (identity x) x)
(define (inc x) (+ 1 x))
(define (sum-integers a b) (i-sum identity a inc b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your answer is correct, although I'm not sure why you need the `identity`, `inc`, and `sum-integers` procedure on the bottom for your solution.

Comment: Not homework - personal growth exercise :)

Comment: @Joshua: Haha okay, just checking. :)

Comment: They're there for testing purposes - I suppose maybe I should have removed them before posting the question?...hmm